# Is there a way to insert a separator when using the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using a `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` in `CDialog` and I would like to insert a separator in between some properties. I can't work out how to do this.

I used Chat GPT and it suggested I inherit from `CMFCPropertyGridCtrlProperty` and set the `m_bIsValueList` to `true` but it did not work for me.

Comment: IIRC `m_bIsValueList ` is not intended for such purpose.